# How to Import photo from screensaver Mac

Tags: mac, screensaver

I have transferred a photo from camera to the Mac and it is  stored in screen saver. I couldn't find any photo in iPhoto or in the library.

If you can please help me how to import photos from screen saver.

Comment: All of the screen savers with ability to use custom photos take the photos from either an iPhoto Library or a folder. Have you checked System Preferences to see where the photos are?

Answer (score 1):

Open the screen saver preference pane and see what folder has the files. If you can locate that, open photos and import from that location.